# How to disable lazy loading globally in Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I read so many articles regarding disabling Fluent NHibernate lazy loading but none of them working. I want to disable lazy loading globally. Can anyone please let me know how to do that.

See below Fluent NHibernate configuration:

```
 _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                .ConnectionString(_connectionString)
                .ShowSql())
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<UserMap>()
                .Conventions.Add(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Helpers.DefaultLazy.Never()))
            .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add global `IReferenceConvention` to remove lazy loading for specific foreign keys:

```cs
public class AggregateAttribute : Attribute {
}

public class ReferenceConvention : IReferenceConvention, IReferenceConventionAcceptance, IHasManyConvention, IHasManyConventionAcceptance {
    public void Apply(IManyToOneInstance instance) {
        instance.Fetch.Join();
    }

    public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IManyToOneInspector> criteria) {
        criteria.Expect(x => x.Property != null && x.Property.MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AggregateAttribute), false).Any());
    }

    public void Apply(IOneToManyCollectionInstance instance) {
        instance.Fetch.Select();
    }

    public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IOneToManyCollectionInspector> criteria) {
        criteria.Expect(x => x.Member != null && x.Member.IsDefined(typeof(AggregateAttribute), false));
    }
}
```

Use aggregate attribute as:

```cs
public class FirstRecord {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    // Disable lazy load
    [Aggregate]
    public SecondRecord SecondRecord { get; set; }
    // Lazy load
    public ThirdRecord ThirdRecord { get; set; }
}

public class SecondRecord {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
}

public class ThirdRecord {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
}
```

This code will remove lazy loading for any property with `Aggregate` attribute on it, if you want to disable lazy for all properties, then remove this attribute and update convention class to be:

```cs
public class ReferenceConvention : IReferenceConvention, IHasManyConvention{
    public void Apply(IManyToOneInstance instance) {
        instance.Fetch.Join();
    }
    public void Apply(IOneToManyCollectionInstance instance) {
        instance.Fetch.Select();
    }
}
```

With this code, nhibernate will auto load many to one relations by join related records in the same query, and one to many by separate query.

To use it, simple register new convention:

```cs
.Conventions.Add(new ReferenceConvention())
```

Comment: Could you please show some example how to use that?

Comment: Still lazy loading happens. I want to disable lazy loading completely. So, my associated properties will be null.